# save the visibility of an item in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have an issue in my list view, when the user click on item , the item become invisible,

but when he return to the listview the item is visible again,i tried the instruction

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but it didn't work ; how to save the visibility of items in

the list view ?? that's my question...thanks for help

MY CODE :

```
         private void populateListViewFromDB() {
    Cursor cursor = db.getAllRecords();
    startManagingCursor(cursor);
    String[] databaseColumnNames = new String[] { DBAdapter.col_Region };
    int[] toViewIDs = new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 };

    SimpleCursorAdapter myCursordapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, cursor,
            databaseColumnNames, toViewIDs, FLAG_REGISTER_CONTENT_OBSERVER);

    final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setAdapter(myCursordapter);
```

HERE my code when i want to make an item invisible  :

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(final AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                final int position, long arg3) {
                ((TextView)arg1).setVisibility(8);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because the adapter is recreating the item's view after you scrolled away, then scrolled back to the initial position. 
You'll probably have to write your own adapter, keep track of the position of the invisible `View`s and set the visibility accordingly in `getView()`.

Comment: See this tutorial on how to create your own Adapter: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Answer (score 1):

when you navigate away from listview, its destroyed and will be recreated when you navigate back to listview. Since you are not handling visiblity state check during creation time, it will always end up being visible.
You might need to extend the listadapter and override getView method.

Comment: thanks for idea, so every time the list will be created, so all the items will be visible, and how could i override getView method ??

Comment: 1. You will need to create a define a class for list objects instead of strings
Eg : 
`class ListItem {
    string text1;
    string text2;
    boolean isText1Visible;
    }
`
2. Write an adapter that can use a list of your custom listitem
3. Override the getView method of the adapter and display the text based on the property.
4. OnClick update the listItem property as required.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an items visibility by calling

```
View.getVisibility();
```

and compare it to

```
View.INVISIBLE or View.VISIBLE
```

then setting the visibility according to your conditions like

```
View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
```

or

```
View.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
```

Comment: that's what i am looking for, but where should i put the conditions in my code ?? thankks

Comment: `OnItemClickListener` of listview

Comment: i am trying to apply your solution, but i don't know where to start, so i should in **OnItemClickListener** try to add condition if an item is visible or not, but that would not be considered because the list is re-created again ?? so what make those conditions have effects ??